# Fast ASCII String processing [Swift]

Tags: swift, string, ascii

I am processing very large log files using a swift program. The language itself is very nice, but the String class is ... too well done, and very slow as a result.

For instance, I am only dealing with ASCII strings, so the 10th character of the string should be accessed very easily by pointer operations like `str[9]`. But the string class does some fancy character and graphemes computation to yield the 'right' result in every situations.

I also need to parse the strings using regular expressions (that, I know is very expansive).

Is there a way to tell Swift to consider strings only as ASCII strings to avoid any expansive unnecessary computations ? Should I use something else ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Have you tried converting the string to an array of characters? `let letters = Array(text)`. You can access the characters with an int subscript like so `letters[4]`

Comment: Have you profiled to see what is actually slow about accessing strings the way that you're trying to? `String` has built-in fast-paths that prioritize quick access for strings thare are known to be ASCII — those strings should be as fast to access as arrays. If you do some time profiling in Instruments for the code that appears slow, what do you see? (And can you share that code?)

Comment: According to this, it’s difficult to outperform strings: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64704550/3723423 - Anyway, lots of code on your devices routinely processes unicode strings without performance issues. Are you sure it’s the strings and not the regexes that you use?

Comment: @Craig: Thx, I will look into it and do some profiling

Comment: @ItaiFerber: Yes, I did profile the code. However, since all I do is processing strings, 98% of the CPU time is spent... processing strings. The most useful info I get is not prom profiling but from benchmarking. For instance, `wc -l`, which counts lines, takes 9.8 minutes to execute. Counting lines with my code takes 12 minutes. And converting the start of each line into a Date object... takes a day and a half. Granted, the file is large and I have over three billion lines...

Comment: @Christophe: I have read the post carefully. Thx for pointing it out. However, it states that is should not be possible to outperform Strings when dealing with the most general case. It is only possible when having some specialized knowledge about the strings that can help speedup the process. I have this specialized knowledge : I am dealing with logs. Only ASCII chars of 1 byte in size are allowed.

Comment: @Anco34 At 3 billion lines, it appears that `wc -l` is taking 196 nanoseconds per line, while your code 240 nanoseconds per line, i.e., an almost _indistinguishable_ difference per line. I think you may be barking up the wrong tree here: the scale of the data is enormous, so any minute differences will add up. You're going to see _way_ bigger wins by processing your data differently, e.g., in parallel across multiple chunks of the file. Or, if that's not feasible, you're going to need to stop treating the data like strings and move to something like SIMD byte arrays.

Comment: (Not to mention that even if you go to great lengths to get the line-splitting portion of the task down to even 2 minutes: if it takes _a day and a half_ to parse all of these dates, it's not the strings which are the problem...)

Comment: If you're able to share some code about what exactly you're doing, we may be able to help cut things down a bit — but this sounds like an _architectural_ challenge more than anything else. (And there are likely way better tools written and optimized for ripping through this much data, even if not in Swift.)